# Custom Timer & Changelists submission on Perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am trying to come up with a way (if its even possible) to make a custom tool for Perforce that will take 3 sets of different but specific changelists and submit them at a custom time and day of the week. Like 15:00:00 on a Sunday.
I have been looking around on the perforce site and here or even an already created tool I could take a look at but I cannot seem to find anything.
Any ideas would be great!
Thanks.

Comment: Are they always the same files, or group of files? I would probably not do it as a custom tool, but script it, than run it as a cronjob or scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a batch file to run the commands. 
It took a while but I managed to make it run with all the arguments it needed.
Here is a snippet of what I ended up doing.

```
SET path=directory 
SET port=portaddress
SET wrk=workspace
SET arg= arguments from a json file

echo Setting up Enviroment
start "" config.bat

echo Running Changlists through arg
start "" %path% %arg% 000000 %wrk% %port%
start "" %path% %arg% 000000 %wrk% %port%
```

There was quite a few good resources I found when coming up with this which may be useful to others who are new to batch.

This was the most helpful : [Batch Help](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchcommands.php)

The Perforce site also helped a lot too : [Perforce](http://ftp.perforce.com/pub/perforce/r05.2/doc/help/p4v-html-pure/custom_tools.html)